# Why does this method work for proving $7|m^2$ thus $7|m$ but it does not work for multiples of 4?

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

I am refreshing my high school math since years of not doing any math at all and saw this method that I cannot fully understand.

According to a math video I watched, the teacher showed that for any number m powered to 2 and divisible by 7, then m is also divisible by 7. If $7|m^2$ then $7|m$.
He then proved using contradiction of the opposite, assuming that while $7|m^2$ is true, $7|m$ is false:

$m \neq 7k$

$m^2 \neq (7k)^2$

$m^2 \neq 7^2k^2$

$m^2 \neq 7(7k^2)$

$k' = 7k^2$

$m^2 \neq 7k'$

And thus, we somehow have a contradiction with the initial statement of $7|m^2$.

I do the same for multiples of 4, I say that if $4|m^2$ then $4|m$ and I am going to prove it by contradiction of the opposite. If $4|m^2$ is true then $4|m$ is false:

$m \neq 4k$

$m^2 \neq (4k)^2$

$m^2 \neq 4^2k^2$

$m^2 \neq 4(7k^2)$

$k' = 4k^2$

$m^2 \neq 4k'$

So same result, this contradiction proved that if $4|m^2$ then $4|m$. But we know it really is not true, $6^2$ is divisible by 4 but 6 is not. So, some questions:

- Is there any flaw in the first demonstration?
- Does this method only works for prime numbers? If so, why? Should have I expressed 4 as $2^2$ instead?

Comment: The initial argument, for $7$, is very hard to follow.  I suggest writing out another proof that $7\,|\,m^2\implies 7\,|\,m$.

Comment: The argument for 7 is not correct. You  got no contradiction, as you have only showed that $m^2$ is not a of the form $7\cdot n$, with $n $ in a proper subset of the integers, namely  in $\{7k^2\mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$. The same for 4...

Comment: See also the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681482/why-this-reductio-ad-absurdum-works-to-show-sqrt7-is-irrational-but-it-does-n) for context.

Comment: The reason the result is true for $7$ and not $4$ is because $7$ is prime and cannot be factored into smaller numbers, each of which can divide $m$. The number $4=2\times 2$ can be factored so that $2$ divides $m$ which means that $4$ can divide $m^2$ without dividing $m$ as in your example.

Comment: So this only works for prime numbers, which was something that was not specified in the video I watched. In another video did specify that and why was like that, with a different example.
Thank you all